# Is a buyer legally exempt of sale taxes when buying a good from a shop located in France from the US?

Tags: united-states, tax-law, france

The buyer lives in the United States. The buyer ordered 100 USD of goods from a shop X located in France. The order was passed through phone. The goods were sent by (physical) mail.

Is shop X legally forced to exempt the buyer from French sale taxes, if the buyer requires so? Or is the French tax exemption at the discretion of shop X?

Comment: @Cicero I think it makes sense that sales tax be determined by law, not by the shop. E.g., when buying in France, sales tax is not up to the shop. Unsure about tax exemption cases, e.g. http://www.douane.gouv.fr/Portals/0/fichiers/information/publication-douane/particuliers/detaxe-pablo-formalites-service-douane.pdf "vous devez effectuer vos achats auprès d’un commerçant proposant la détaxe".

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.